# Ember Data RestAdapter find() doesn't appear to be returning a record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following code which works in Ember Data Beta 8.

```
return store.find('user', userId).then(function(user) {
  return {
    currentUser: user
  };
});
```

As soon as I upgrade to Beta 9 the code appears to fail to return the currentUser object. This is using the ActiveModelAdapter.  I can't spot anything that different between the RESTAdapter find or ajax methods between Beta 8 and 9.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you console out the user, what is it?

Comment: In Beta 8, it's the user model.  In Beta 9 it's the promise.

Comment: Here is a little example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/raqoge/1/edit Could you please extend, what is your context and where would you like to use the above snippet?

Comment: Completely rewritten this area of the code, so didn't end up finding out the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

In recent Ember-Data betas `Store.find()` will always return a promise, even if the record is already in the store.

You can read the latest docs for Store.find [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L354).